# How to obtain iPhone's heading when it is rotated fast

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, orientation

I am programming an iPhone app in ios 6 where I obtain the heading information and then using simple calculations, I convert that information to words, as "You are facing west". Now my problem is, when I rotate my phone from (say) north to east, phone will point out: 1. You are facing north-east (3-4 times) then at last when the phone settles, it says 2. You are facing east. The problem is I am converting all the commands to speech, and it turns out to be confusing and disturbing.

One way is to increase the value of heading filter, but I can't do that since I need precision of 20 degrees. I tried to use `timestamps` of headings, but no use. I tried `usleep()` but no use since the entire program stops. Is there any way I could tell phone to take information at 1.5 seconds interval from location manager, or can the location manager itself be programmed to check for heading after the phone's rotation has stabilized.

Update: How I failed in using timestamps ->

Suppose I move my phone fast my north to east. The difference in stamps look like this:

(all values in seconds, this value can be arbitrarily large or even undefined since I am moving the phone for the first time, in this case, it is 10 seconds which indicates I rotated the phone from west to north 10 seconds before)

10, 0.0012, 0.012, 0.005 (phone settles and the location manager is not called again). I do not know how to detect that I should take the value corresponding to 0.005.

Comment: Just prevent the message from being said more than once.

Comment: How? How to know that the phone has settled? Also, if I prevent the phone from saying the message out for the second time, I would be doing a wrong thing, since first information (facing north-east) is temporary and misleading

Comment: Ok. I will look into CMMotionManager. Thanks. Also I am using `locationManager: didUpdateHeading` method

Comment: When you recieve didupdateheading, compare the value you get with the one you got the last time (maybe the time before too)and then maybe you could determine if the heading is moving or not.

Comment: I will watch this question and if you don't have an answer I maybe could type some code but now isn't a great time.

Comment: I considered that but it doesn't work. The heading is continuously moving, suppose I have precision of 20 degrees and I moved from 0 to 90, then the log shows this: The heading is 0, 20, 40, 60, 90. So no way to know that 90 is the correct value.

Comment: What is after 90? Does it stop moving?

Comment: 0 is the initial heading and 90 is final where I stop rotating the phone. Consider it as rotation from North to East. So the location manager will print out all the values at an interval of 20 degrees. In short, the heading given is correct, but I want to control its frequency or find a way to determine that the phone has stabilized so that I can print out that information.

Comment: Yes, I'm saying that you could have your program somehow detect when there is no more motion so that it could tell that it stopped moving

Comment: You could record how long is in between calls of didupdateheading

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33171/discussion-between-unicorn-and-parag)